# Analyze a particular example of approximation for $\int_N^M(\sin(\pi(t)))^2dt$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I was playing with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) when I wondered what about the asymptotic behaviour as $x\to\infty $ of $$\int_1^x\sin^2(\pi(t))dt,\tag{1}$$
where $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function, and the integrand is the square of such sine function, that is $\sin^2(\pi(u))$ means $(\sin(\pi(u)))^2$. Here you've these codes

`plot (sin(primepi(x)))^2, for 1<x<100`

`plot (sin(primepi(x)))^2, for 1<x<10000`

versus

`plot (sin(x/log(x)))^2, for 2<x<10000`

I think that study the asymptotic behaviour of $(1)$ is very difficult, thus I ask this question about if you can provide me calculations for an example.

> **Question.** What work can be done to study the area under the graph of $f(y)=\sin^2(\pi(y))$ over a segment $[N,M]$, where $N<M$ are large positive  integers, that is the behaviour of an example* $$\int_N^M\sin^2(\pi(t))dt?\tag{2}$$
>   *To me only is required the analysis of an example for some *large* $N<M$. **Many thanks.**

That I am asking is if you can do some work about it.

Comment: You can take the word *large* for our integers/reals $N<M$ as you need in your example, and $M$ as a function of $N$ if you need it, with the purpose to show your work in such example that I evoke.

Comment: Maybe are required calculations using the Riemann–Stieltjes integral.